# cocos2d sigleton array is not adding objects

Tags: objective-c, arrays, cocos2d-iphone, ccsprite

Sorry for my bad english

i search over the internet and i saw how to but for some reason is not adding objects;
what i want to do is load on a layer my power up sprites and add them on an array and based on the array i will choose which ones to show and when on a different layer.

i am sure its a silly detail but i cant understand what.
if i create a local array and use instead of the singleton is working.

i made a game manager class

```
//header

@interface GameManager : NSObject {
}

@property (nonatomic,retain) NSMutableArray *powerUpsArray;

+(GameManager*)sharedGameManager;
@end
```

implementation

```
@implementation GameManager

static GameManager* _sharedGameManager = nil;

@synthesize powerUpsArray=_powerUpsArray;

+(GameManager*)sharedGameManager {
@synchronized([GameManager class]) 
{
    if(!_sharedGameManager) 
        [[self alloc] init];
    return _sharedGameManager;
}
return nil;
}


-(id)init {
self = [super init];
if (self != nil) {
    self.powerUpsArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
}
return self;
}
@end
```

and i do import the header and on the layer i do on init method

```
[[GameManager sharedGameManager].powerUpsArray addObject:[[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] spriteFrameByName:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"bomb.png"]]];
```

i have created the batchnode and i did the framcache from frame,any ideas why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try...

```
if(!_sharedGameManager) 
    _sharedGameManager = [[self alloc] init];
```

As it is, you're creating objects but not updating your static variable with them.